# What does mean NC in an schematic and BOM?

Tags: circuit-design, schematics, usb-pd, bom

I am reading this [datasheet](https://www.hynetek.com/uploadfiles/site/219/news/d45ab9c8-5dd6-46d5-8572-95e337dd3467.pdf) to implement that IC for an USB-C PD module to charge a 2-S battery pack, but I have the doubt in the schematic (page 11).  There are some capacitors with value NC which I do not understand.  I think it could be mean Non-connected, but why would they be present in the schematic if are not connected?

I also have another doubt related to the Zener diodes (ZD1, ZD2, ZD3, ZD4) in the BOM. It says Material name ESD Pipe, description: NC , items: ZD1,ZD2,ZD3,ZD4,D1,D2, in the same way for the capacitors and resistor highlighted in the following images.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- BOM — bill of materials — shopping list
- NC — no connection / do not connect

NC is used the wrong way in this BOM. It should say “spare” instead.

Comment: thank you Janka, so that means I should have to delete those parts in the schematic given that I do not know the values?

Comment: You should not delete them but reserve space on the board for them and also draw all the tracks needed to connect them. But then you don't put actual parts there. At least not by default.

Comment: You might find that something is actually installed in those locations if they're sites for select-at-test components.

Comment: Not populated (NP) is sometimes used to designate a component that, for various reasons, does not have to be installed on the PCB.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will contact the manufacturer with all this information